# What is a "SocketTimeoutException connect time out" and how do I fix it?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming, socket-timeout-exception

I am trying to call my remote  tomcat server from java client but i intermittently get SocketTimeoutException: connection time out. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html)

here is the stack trace

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:382)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:228)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:365)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:570)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.contrib.ssl.EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:189)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:706)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:386)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
```

It is not consistent, it goes away after my code makes multiple attempt to connect.

i understand what socketTimeout means, I am not getting read time out but connect time out, which means client fails to setup tcp connection with the server.Meaning server just disregards the clients attempt to connect it, as either its not available or too busy doing something else on that port. I know my server is reachable and up and running.

apparently my attempt to connect to the server is being refused, i want to figure out why? how do i get started? what should i look for? my server runs on redhat linux  box running on an EC2 instance, is there a way i can look at why my connection is being refused?

Comment: What is the *exact* exception? You've given two versions. I would have expected either ConnectException: 'connect timeout', when trying to connect, or SocketTimeoutException: 'connection timed out', when doing I/O.

Comment: You should add more detail, what "server", framework, language, purpose, logs you've already checked? Same network? remote? vpn? Protocol being used? Now you're just saying "my program is broken"

Comment: updated the description, let me know if it makes more sense now, or you want any other specific details.Thanks.

Comment: Please make sure you have posted the *exact* exception and error message. I asked you that before. I still don't believe you've done it. Please also include the stack trace.

Comment: added the exception and the stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

Probable cause is other process or Tomcat itself consuming resources makes the app unresponsive.

Start monitoring server resources:

- CPU
- Memory
- Network activity
- Open handles(are you running on linux?)

Intermittence can be explained because only when the server is under load connection fails.

You can also try to increase connection timeout on the server [as in this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619222/tomcat-connection-timeout).

Comment: No it isn't. That would cause read timeouts, not 'connection timed out'.

Comment: Who says so? If you are out of handles the server won't be able to accept a new connection, open a socket, launch a thread, etc. `ulimit -a`

Comment: If you are out of reources the server *process* won't be able to get a new socket from `accept()`, but the operating system creates the connections on the backlog queue prior to this. So reource exhaustion does not account for connect timeouts.